# Delaunaymesh boundary effects

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

I have generated a Delaunay mesh region from the seeds, shown like following:

[image]

This is a zoomed-in crop image, showing the bottom left corner.
The black dots are the seeds. The continuous black lines are the Delaunay mesh.
The problem is that we can find some boundary effects on the outer seeds(shown in red circles), and I want to generate a Delaunay mesh without them.

I don't mind to delete all the outermost seeds and generate a mesh with seeds left inner, but it still exists. And I tried constrained Delaunay mesh it failed again.

Is there a way to solve this? Thank you!

The seeds are generated from following picture and codes:
[image: bw]

```
imgt=Import["bw.JPG"]
k = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[imgt]] // ImageAdjust;
ReliefPlot[Reverse@ImageData[k]]; (*To illustrate*)
l = ColorNegate[Binarize[ColorNegate[LaplacianGaussianFilter[k, 4] //ImageAdjust]]];

meanValues = ComponentMeasurements[l, {"Centroid"}];
listData = meanValues /. Rule -> List;
listData = Partition[Flatten[listData[[All, 2]]], 2];
imgBounds = Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[imgt]}];

R = DelaunayMesh[listData,imgBounds];
HighlightMesh[R, Style[0, Black]]
```

listData is the seeds here.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the image. This will help others in giving you a solution

Comment: I have revised it, thank you for your suggestion.